# C++ BF Search using pointer queue

Tags: c++, pointers, queue, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

Ok so im trying to use the template file provided to me, BTNode is a part of that template. anyway, im trying to use a queue of type btnode to store the pointers to the nodes of the binary search tree, then i pass the data that the pointer in queue.front() points to into process f. then i store the pointers to the children of that node and pop the parent off the queue. then repeat. atleast thats what im trying to do.

im just not sure how to go about fixing the warnings and errors that im getting, which all have to do with the queue in some way.
am i not pushing pointers into the queue? how do i fix this?

```
template <class Process, class BTNode>
void breadthfirst(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
{
    std::queue<BTNode> map;
    if(node_ptr != NULL)
    map.push(node_ptr);

    while(!map.empty()){
        int a = map.front()*;
        f(a);
        if( map.front() -> right() != NULL)
            map.push(map.front() -> right());

        if(map.front() -> left() != NULL)
            map.push(map.front() -> left());

        map.pop();
    }

}
```

.

Answer (score 0):

never mind everyone, i was just missing the asterisk on btnode for queue type